# react inline function in jsx in one line

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just curious is it possible to do this? I know I can create a method that wrap these 2 things together but I would like to do it in one line.

```
<div onClick={e => this.callnotherMethod(); this.setState({toggleView: !this.state.toggleView})/>Something</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.
But in your example you forgot to wrap function's body in `{}`

```
e => { this.callnotherMethod(); this.setState({toggleView: !this.state.toggleView}) }
```

Comment: I think your first answer was correct, no need to `that` as you are already using arrow functions for binding

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri you're right! I totally missed it )) Thanks.